# The page number position changing within the same document?

Tags: page-numbering

The position of the page number is changing within the same chapter. Specifically, the first page is shown correctly (on the bottom of the page), but the rest of that chapter is shown on the bottom top right.

I want the page number to be shown on the right bottom for the entire text!

MVE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdftitle={Internship report}, pdfauthor={Kristjan Qarri}, pdfsubject={Internship report}, pdfkeywords={<keywords here>}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}
{\sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% add references in the TOC
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
%%%%%%%%%%%
% acronyms
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{iso}{ISO}{international organization for standardization}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
% end of file

\include{sections/Introduction}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[Link to the project file](https://www.overleaf.com/read/yqqqppvgvgwk)

[image: This is what the page nr position looks like.]

Comment: that is the standard behaviour, chapter openings are shown with `\thispagestyle{plain}` so that they have an empty header and put the page number at the bottom, leaving the top free for a fancy title layout. The `fancyhdr` package  gives easy commands to customise the page head and foot on normal and chapter opening pages (look for fancyplain in the manual)

Comment: Note that you are using titlesec to create mystyle.

Comment: I solved it by disabling the header option. That puts by default the page nr on the bottom of the page for all pages of the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is shown in the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdftitle={Internship report}, pdfauthor={Kristjan Qarri}, pdfsubject={Internship report}, pdfkeywords={<keywords here>}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%% Change from here
%\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
%\pagestyle{mystyle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% add references in the TOC
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
%%%%%%%%%%%
% acronyms
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{iso}{ISO}{international organization for standardization}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
% end of file
% Kristjan Qarri
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```